# Will my Ubuntu One account expire if I don't use it regularly?

Tags: ubuntu-one, time

As happens with webmail emails after a certain time without access to the account, these are removed, is this the same with Ubuntu One, and what length of time would an account have to be inactive for it to be closed?

Thank you very much in advance and best regards.

Comment: Specify which account you are referring to - the user account on your Ubuntu install or the account you are using to log in here at askubuntu or the one you are using to log into ubuntuforums.org

Answer (score 1):

I asked the Ubuntu One support team this question and the response was:

> Currently we do not deactivate accounts for inactivity

[Source](https://twitter.com/#!/UbuntuOne/status/189392459422384128)